# Is it possible to automatically create inverse relationships in a core data model?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, core-data

The core data model of my app features about 50 entities with a lot of relationships between them. All of the relationships are uni-directional only (and are only required in one direction).

However Apple discourages you from leaving relationships without inverse (for model consistency reasons) and I believe that the missing inverses are responsible for a number of errors I am currently facing.

Since I don't really need the inverse relationships functionality-wise, I wonder if it would be possible to have them created automatically by XCode. Going through 50 entities with about 3 relationships each and creating inverses manually seems like a tedious task...

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure whether my answer is correct but as far as I saw there was no automatic way to do it.. If I am wrong, please do correct me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to have the inverse relationship automatically created in for you in Xcode4. Please file a feature request bug report for it.  I could see this being a really useful feature in Xcode.

Comment: I'll accept your answer because unfortunately, I have come to the same conclusion. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It may be impossible to automatically generate inverse relationship without generating proxy class. For example how to generate inverse relationship for a collection that occurs more than one time in a class (e.g. phones, mails, urls in business card)